# parallel_for_each

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have constructed a simple implementation of a parallel loop:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>
#include "stdqueue.h"

namespace Wide {
    namespace Concurrency {
        template<typename Iterator, typename Func> void ParallelForEach(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Func f) {
            std::vector<Iterator> its;
            while(begin != end)
                its.push_back(begin++);
            Queue<Iterator> its_queue(its.begin(), its.end());
            auto threadnum = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() + 1;
            std::atomic<bool> exception = false;
            std::mutex exception_lock;
            std::exception_ptr except;
            std::vector<std::thread> threads;
            for(int i = 0; i < threadnum; ++i) {
                threads.push_back(std::thread([&] {
                    while(true) {
                        Iterator it;
                        if (!its_queue.try_pop(it))
                            break;
                        if (exception)
                            return;
                        try {
                            f(*it);
                        } catch(...) {
                            std::lock_guard lm(exception_lock);
                            except = std::current_exception();
                            exception = true;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }
            for(auto&& thr : threads)
                thr.join();
            if (exception)
                std::rethrow_exception(except);
        }
    }
}
```

The only non-standard class here is `Queue`, and it is simply a mutex over a `std::queue`, essentially (at least in this code path), although I have encapsulated the attempt to pop an object off into a single function `try_pop`, which you will recognize from PPL and TBB.

Also note that `f` will be hefty, not a light function at all. It is also likely that each invocation of `f` will run slightly different times depending on the contents of `*it`.

Kindly comment on the performance and safety of this function. I am obviously more concerned about safety than performance, so highly complex tricks to earn more performance are likely not viable for me.

Comment: I can see a few errors that will stop this from even compiling. It should be `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` for one. Depending on your compiler, it may barf at `std::vector<std::thread>` followed by `push_back(std::thread)`. You're likely better off doing `std::vector<std::thread> threads(threadnum)` followed by a `threads[i] = std::thread(...)`.

Comment: @Yuushi it should be `vector<unique_ptr<thread>>` then.

Answer (score 3):

First, that `begin/end` range, `its` and `its_queue` are duplicates of each other.
If we change `Iterator` to `RandomAccessIterator`, we can get rid of them:

```
template<typename RA_Iterator, typename Func> void ParallelForEach(RA_Iterator begin, RA_Iterator end, Func f) {
    const auto size = end - begin;
    std::atomic<std::size_t> pos = 0;

    ...
        std::thread([&] {
            while(true) {
                auto i = pos.fetch_add(1);
                if (i >= size)
                    break;

                ...
                f(*(begin + i));
```

Second, creating threads for each `ForEach` costs a lot. Writing all that exception-transferring boilerplate doesn't look good either. That's why I'd use `std::async` which probably could reuse threads and also can deal with exceptions.

```
    std::atomic<bool> exception = false;
    std::vector<std::future<void>> threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < threadnum; ++i) {
        threads.push_back(std::async([&] {
            MyScopeExit onExit([&]{ exception = true; });
            while(true) {
                ...                
                if (exception)
                    break;

                f(*it);
            }
            onExit.disarm();
        }));
    }
    for(auto&& thr : threads)
        thr.get();
```

And finally, the code could look like this:

```
    const auto size = end - begin;
    std::atomic<std::size_t> pos = 0;
    ...
    std::vector<std::future<void>> threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < threadnum; ++i) {
        threads.push_back(std::async([&] {
            MyScopeExit onExit([&]{ pos = size; });
            while(true) {
                auto i = pos.fetch_add(1);
                if (i >= size)
                    break;

                f(*(begin + i));
            }
            onExit.disarm();
        }));
    }
    for(auto&& thr : threads)
        thr.get();
```